# how to replace strings in a file using a loop counter

Tags: python, string, for-loop, replace, count

I have a file named: `my_file.txt`

And inside this `my_file.txt`, I have some strings such as:

`name1 name1 name1 name1 name1 name1 name1 name1 name1 name1`

And I need to do a bulk loop counter on that 1 to 10 to look like:

`name1 name2 name3 name4 name5 name6 name7 name8 name9 name10`

So far I only have this, which I found here:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file-in-python

But that just swaps one string for another. And I need to use the counter.

```
search_text = "dummy"

replace_text = "replaced"

with open(r'my_file.txt', 'r') as file:

    data = file.read()
    data = data.replace(search_text, replace_text)

with open(r'my_file.txt', 'w') as file:

    file.write(data)

print("Text replaced")
```

Comment: Is there only one line in your my_file.txt ?

Comment: They are lines one under the other, but I used it only as an example to simplify.

Comment: So your counter need to over the lines or just in one line. And it's more nice to make your demo data and demo code un-oppose. demo data use `name` but `dummy` and `replaced` in code, is bad example.

Comment: Your simplify example covered the things you need to tell. name1 name1 name1\nname2 name2 name2 to name11 name12 name23\nname21 name22 name23. and so on. There are too many cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do iterative replace and replacing one occurence at each time.

Work with chunks to improve performance in case the string is very very big

```py
with open(r'my_file.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
    
search_text = "dummy"
replace_text = "replaced"
n_replaced = 0
index = 0


chunks = []
while True:
    index = data.find(search_text)
    if index == -1:
        break
    replace_text_counter = f"{replace_text}{n_replaced}"
    chunks.append(data[:index])
    data = data[index:].replace(search_text, replace_text_counter, 1)
    n_replaced += 1
chunks.append(data)

with open(r'my_file.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write("".join(chunks))

print("Text replaced")
```

Comment: Wherever on the planet you are, may my sincere thanks reach you.

I celebrated with joy, as I had been looking for a solution like yours for days on my own.

Thank you very much, I wish you all the success in the world friend! Hugs!

Comment: I am glad I could help you my friend, all the best for you to.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the read and write file and lines in your case. I give a code just deal with string line which you gave `name1 name1 name1 name1 name1 name1 name1 name1 name1 name1`:

```py
string = "name1 name1 name1 name1 name1 name1 name1 name1 name1 name1"
li = string.split()
i=0
for i<len(li):
  li[i]=li[i].replace("1",i+1)
return ' '.join(li)
```